# compare 2 strings, determine whether A contains all of the characters in B in python using list

Tags: string, list, data-structures

question is :

## Compare two strings A and B, determine whether A contains all of the characters in B.

## The characters in string A and B are all Upper Case letters.

and I saw the solution is:

```
def compareStrings(self, A, B):
    if len(B) == 0:
        return True
    if len(A) == 0:
        return False
    trackTable = [0 for _ in range(26)]
    for i in A:
        trackTable[ord(i) - 65] += 1
    for i in B:
        if trackTable[ord(i) - 65] == 0:
            return False
        else:
            trackTable[ord(i) -65] -= 1
    return True
```

I do not understand :
1) why give 26  '0'  in the list at beginning ?
2) what does trackTable[ord(i) - 65] += 1 do ?
what is ord(i)?

Thanks !
Min

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an interesting solution for sure (it's pretty convoluted). It creates a 26-element array to count the occurences of each letter in A, then makes sure that the count for each of those letters in B is greater than or equal to the count in A.

To directly answer your questions:

1) why give 26 '0' in the list at beginning ?

We are starting with a list of 26 0's, one for each letter A-Z. We will increment this in the first `for` loop.

2) what does trackTable[ord(i) - 65] += 1 do ?

This does the counting. Assuming the input is just capital letters A-Z, then ord('A')=65 and ord('Z')=90. We subtract 65 to make this range from 0-25.

3) what is ord(i)?

I would recommend searching online for this. https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/ord

"The ord() method returns an integer representing Unicode code point for the given Unicode character."